# signal occurrence intervals / signal arrival interval / signal return period /

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology

Let there be given a sequence of some signals.
 
For ex.,
At time 0 the 1st signal appears.
At time 3 seconds the 2nd appears (1st continuing).
4 sec, 1st disappears.
6 sec, 3rd appears, (2nd continuing).
7 sec, 2nd disappears.
9 sec, 4th appears, (3rd continuing).
And so on.
Moreover, the appearances and disappearances are not momentary but gradual.

Please help me choose the term that defines the time interval which is 3 seconds in the above example. Could it be

signal(s) occurrence intervals,
interval between signal(s) arrival(s), 
signal(s) arrival(s) interval,
return period?

or some else?

Words such as "rate", "frequency", etc., do not fit because the term should mean exactly time interval, this time interval will need to be compared with another time interval (“...in the case when the _______ is less than the time required for the operation execution.”).

Especially valuable for me would be a native English speaker's answer with a technical background.

P.S. I will be grateful if you indicate all grammatical or syntax errors in my posts, if any.

Comment: I think you'll get better answers at https://physics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why does *rate* not fit? *The signals appear at the rate of 1 new signal every 3 seconds.*

Comment: michael.hor257k, because I cannot say “the rate less than the time required for the operation execution.”

Comment: How about “the rate less than the duration of a signal”?

Comment: Weather Vane, I seem it is not correct to compare rate with duration. “Rate” means the number of some events per second, minute, etc. “Duration” is measured in seconds or minutes. This is exactly the same as we can not compare length (in meters) with mass (in kilograms). However, I am not a native English speaker. Correct me please if I am wrong.

Comment: @Diusha You are right, for such comparison you should use *interval*.

Comment: *Signal occurrence interval* seems to work best.

*Interval between arrivals* might be technically accurate but it suggests arrival is more important than transit or generation time. Is that the case?

*Signal arrival interval* suffers in the same way.

*Return period* could only work if you sent and received and returned the signal. Is that the case?

In English you so clearly can’t say *the rate less than the time required for the operation execution* that in physics it’s hard to follow and I suggest you can say exactly that.

More…

Comment: Rates and times are not directly comparable; neither in English nor in physics.

*operation execution* is understandable yet it would better be *execution of the operation* or simply *the operation* or even *execution* and please note that *the*.

Comment: In general, you should use the same terminology that is used by others in the specific area of science/technology being discussed.

Comment: Are these signals arriving on the same communication channel or on parallel channels? For instance are they all coming down a single piece of copper wire with the same carrier frequency? If this is the case then the signals will inerfere and augment or cancel out each other. Is that the point you are trying to make?

Answer (score 1):

*Period*, [see def. 6 here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/period), is typically used in this context.  It has units of time, e.g. seconds;  it’s inverse is the frequency.

> In the case when the period is less than 5 seconds ...

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for "**cycle**".

> - an interval of time during which a sequence of a recurring succession of events or phenomena is completed
> - a course or series of events or operations that recur regularly and usually lead back to the starting point

(Merriam-Webster)

Perhaps with a combination of "**series**"

> - a number of things or events of the same class coming one after another in spatial or temporal succession

(ibid.)

For something like:

"The series of signals cycled every three seconds."

. . . or:

"The signal series was on a three-second cycle."

Comment: Thank you. But I need a phrase that can be substituted in the sentence *“...in the case when the _______ is less than the time required for...”*.
Are the phrases 
 *“signal series cycle interval”* 
or 
*“signal series cycle period”*
correct and clear?

Comment: I think ". . . in the case when the cycle period is less than the time required for . . ." would make sense in context, but of course your mileage may vary.